# What's the difference between TypeRef and Type?

Tags: scala, reflection

I can see that `reflect.runtime.TypeRef` has three extra methods over `reflect.runtime.Type`, but what's the principal difference between the two? Why doesn't `Type` already contain those methods? And how am I supposed to retrieve the values of `TypeRef`?

Comment: In general a `Type` can be cast or matched to `TypeRef` - you see this over and over again in reflection examples. I think the actual question of interest might be "when is a `Type` not a `TypeRef`?".

Comment: One interesting case is that of an existential type such as `List[_]`, which can be cast to `TypeRef`, but throws an exception when you attempt to access `args`. This actually smacks of a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [canonical type pattern match](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.0-M8/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Types.scala#L22) shows everything that is not a `TypeRef`, viz, everything following the `TypeRef` extractor.

For instance a method type doesn't take type params in the same way as a class.  `f[Int]` does not mean "f specialized for Int" the way `List[Int]` is a subtype of `List[Any]` or similarly for `String => Int` and `String => Any`.  So a method type doesn't have type args.